# Display proverbs daily in a widget - Android

Tags: java, android, widget

I made a widget that is supposed to display a random proverb each day so far everything is working fine except that the proverb is not changing, `for testing purposes I set the timer for 3 secondes`

Here's my code:

**JAVA**

```
public class ProverbsWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static int TIME_OUT = 3000; //1000 = 1 sec
public static String fnl_hv = RandomizedProverb(); //this is the method that generates the randem proverb and it's working fine

static void updateAppWidget(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            final int appWidgetId) {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                String widgetText = fnl_hv;

                // Construct the RemoteViews object
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.proverbs_widget);
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.sayings, widgetText);

                // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
        },TIME_OUT);
}
```

The `RandomizeProverb()` :

```
public static String RandomizedProverb(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    String [] Quotes = new String []{
            "test 1",
            "test 2",
            "test 3",
            "test 4",
            "test 5",
            "test 6",
            "test 7",
            "test 8",
            "test 9",
            "test 10",
            "test 11",
            "test 12",
            "test 13",
            "test 14",
            "test 15",
            "test 16",
            "test 17",
            "test 18",
            "test 19",
            "test 20",
    };

    String havm = Quotes[rand.nextInt(20)];
    String hav = havm;
    return hav;
}
```

Clearly the problem is within my timer but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: This is because you only get the randomized string on the class creation. And never change it in your Runnable. So, it stays as it was originally, forever.

Comment: @ModularSynth can you propose a fix for this ?

Comment: Obviously enough, copy this `fnl_hv = RandomizedProverb();` into the `run()` method.

Comment: @ModularSynth unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: Then `RandomizedProverb()` has some problem.

Comment: @ModularSynth check my question I added the method (as far as I know it's working just fine)

Comment: What I would do: `return Quotes[rand.nextInt(19)];` [WARNING: **20** would generate an **IndexOutOfBoundsException**] or simply `return Quotes[rand.nextInt()];`

Comment: still the same, I am not getting the updates, the value is not changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by accessing the XML file and setting the value of `updatePeriodMillis` to `86400000` like so :

```
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
```

Basically this tells the widget when to update itself and when the time is up the method `updateAppWidget()` will be executed and since 86400000 is the number of milliseconds that exist in 24 hours, the widget will be updated daily

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                String widgetText = fnl_hv;

                // Construct the RemoteViews object
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.proverbs_widget);
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.sayings, widgetText);

                // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, timetoswitch);
            }
        },InitialDelayTime;
```

Hope it helps!!!